# How to create unique id for each html elements inside a for loop in ejs template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, express, ejs

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hiddentext').hide();

  $("#show").click(function() {
    $('#currenttext').hide();
    $('#hiddentext').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<% for (var ans of quest.answers) { %>
  <div id="currenttext"><%= ans.text %></div>
  <div id="hiddentext"><%= ans.description %></div>
  <a id="show" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">show</a>
<% } %>
```

I have multiple show button along with its associated HTML element inside my `for` loop. I am having a problem in creating unique `id`s for each HTML element. As for now, on clicking any of the show buttons the functionality is applied on all of the other HTML elements rather than being applied only on its associated elements. Also I have an unique `_id` attribute of `ans` i.e `ans._id` but I don't know to make use of it to create a unique id for my HTML tag from that and how to use that unique id inside my jQuery function.

Comment: `<div id="<%= ans._id %>">` or `<div id="some-prefix-<%= ans._id %>">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the hidden ones with css so they are immediately hidden on page load.

Wrap each group in a container and uses classes and traverses

```js
$('.show').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().toggle();
})
```

```css
.hiddentext {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="currenttext">Answer #1</div>
  <div class="hiddentext">Descrip #1</div>
  <a class="show btn btn-sm btn-primary">Show</a>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="currenttext">Answer #2</div>
  <div class="hiddentext">Descrip #2</div>
  <a class="show btn btn-sm btn-primary">Show</a>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="currenttext">Answer #3</div>
  <div class="hiddentext">Descrip #3</div>
  <a class="show btn btn-sm btn-primary">Show</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I was considering toggle too, but they were not siblings until I made them siblings and then I forgot about toggle ;) - it is likely more elegant if there are no changes

Comment: @LuísMelo what is this all about? That link is invalid...returns a 404

Answer (score 1):

No need for IDs

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hiddentext').hide(); // can be done in CSS
  $(".show").click(function() {
    $(this).prevAll('.currenttext').hide();
    $(this).prevAll('.hiddentext').show();
    // or $(this).siblings().toggle() as suggested in other post
  });
});
```

```html
<% for (var ans of quest.answers) { %>
  <div>
    <div class="currenttext"> <%= ans.text %> </div>
    <div class="hiddentext"> <%= ans.description %> </div>
    <a class="show" class="show btn btn-sm btn-primary">show</a>
  </div>
<% } %>
```